# What type is used to store byte strings in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to store byte strings in a PostgreSQL database using SQLAlchemy.

My model looks like this:

```
class UserAccount(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String)
    password_salt = db.Column(db.String)
```

I want `password_hash` and `password_salt` to both be byte strings (i.e. str, since I'm using Python 2.7), but even if I pass bytes into it, SQLAlchemy seems to turn them into unicode. I've also tried using `convert_unicode=False` in the model, but I get the same result.

What do I use to store bytes in a SQLAlchemy model?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use the [`LargeBinary`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.LargeBinary) type, which will use the [`bytea`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html) type on PostgreSQL. You can also use the [`BYTEA`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.BYTEA) type directly if you're only going to use PostgreSQL.

There are other SQL standard types, such as `BINARY`, but it's typically easier to use `LargeBinary` since SQLAlchemy will use the preferred type for each database.

Answer (score 7):

For shorter byte strings you can also use [TypeDcorator](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#augmenting-existing-types), to wrap the `String` column class. Then use your custom type class `HexByteString` as the `Column` type:

```py
from sqlalchemy.types import Column, String, TypeDecorator
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


class HexByteString(TypeDecorator):
    """Convert Python bytestring to string with hexadecimal digits and back for storage."""

    impl = String

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if not isinstance(value, bytes):
            raise TypeError("HexByteString columns support only bytes values.")
        return value.hex()

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return bytes.fromhex(value) if value else None


Base = declarative_base()

class MyModel(Base):
    data = Column(HexByteString)
```

You can then assign `bytes` instances to the `data` attribute of `MyModel` instances and they will be converted to strings with hexdecimal digits and back when passed to/from the database. This will double the storage size, of course, but makes it easier to see what's stored in the column when looking at the database directly.

You can replace `bytes.hex()` / `bytes.fromhex()` (which needs Python 3.5+) with any other encoding scheme which safely stores bytes in Ascii strings, for example Base64 (`base64.b64_encode(value).decode()` / `base64.b64_decode(value)`).